Uploading folders and files from a single input field in js/ts
I want to upload multiple files and folders from a single input, but unable to do so.


<input
  type="file"
  onChange={handleFileChange}
  className="hidden"
  id="file-input"
  multiple
  ref={fileInputRef}
/>



I was doing above code for uploading file and updated it to following


<input
  type="file"
  onChange={handleFileChange}
  className="hidden"
  id="file-input"
  multiple
  directory=""
  webkitdirectory=""
  mozdirectory=""
  ref={fileInputRef}
/>



But then I was only able to upload folders, not files

as I checked it is because you are using
directory=""
webkitdirectory=""
mozdirectory=""

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory
The HTMLInputElement.webkitdirectory is a property that reflects the webkitdirectory HTML attribute and indicates that the  element should let the user select directories instead of files.
